# Write Unit test for screen with no user input or interaction

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit

I want to write a unit test for my app.  For login or signup pages, it's easy to write tests for validation, error messages etc.

The issue is that I want to write a unit test for a splash screen. 
(Which is show random logo for 5 seconds and redirect the user to login page)

My question is: What is the test cases or scenarios I should write for this kind of screen?

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32070916/android-testing-splash-screen) which is close to what I want, but with Robolectric. (I don't want Robolectric)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running a timer in a single test method? The only thing is you have not to mix this test with the other ones.

Comment: Actually i didn't tried yet, but what in my mind is to test that the next screen is launched after five second but idk how to implement it

Comment: What u mean is to test that start activity line called after 5 seconds?

Comment: I just edited your post to make it more clear.  Check it over to make sure it still says what you want it to :)

Comment: Thanks @cullub some times when u are in rush u just focus on what u want to do :)